# Shared preference max capacity

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I am going to use SharedPreference to save an array of strings with 30,000 elements.
When I define every SharedPreference class it takes 4KB space of phone storage.
Now the thing which I worry about is that, will it be sufficient for such an array?